# What are the other ways to specify code for Insight to analyze?

Tags: spring-insight

Spring Insight [documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.9/operations/about.html) states:

> A trace represents a thread of execution. It is usually started by an HTTP request but can also be started by a background job

My application architecture style is one of queues running in the background that I'd like to instrument as well.  However, I can't figure out how to get Spring Insight to instrument these calls initiated by queued message.  I.e. I'd like to instrument the trace after a message is read off of the queue.

How can I ensure Insight instruments these background jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an aspect that targets all of the Command Handlers.  It extends the `AbstractOperationCollectionAspect`, implements the `collectionPoint` aspect passing in the Handler as an argument to use when it implements the `createOperation` method.
I.e.

```
public aspect CommandHandlerOperationCollectionAspect extends AbstractOperationCollectionAspect
{

    public pointcut collectionPoint():
            execution(* com.xtrac.common.core.handler.ThreadedHandler.HandlerRunnable.executeActorHandler(com.xtrac.common.core.handler.Handler,java.lang.Object));


    protected Operation createOperation(JoinPoint jp)
    {
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
        com.xtrac.common.core.handler.Handler handler = (Handler) args[0];
        Operation operation = new Operation()
                .type(XTRACOperationType.COMMAND_HANDLER)
                .label(handler.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .sourceCodeLocation(getSourceCodeLocation(jp));
        return operation;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPluginName()
    {
        return HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor.PLUGIN_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMetricsGenerator()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also implemented an `AbstractSingleTypeEndpointAnalyzer` to fill out the analyzer:
    public class HandlerEndPointAnalyzer extends AbstractSingleTypeEndpointAnalyzer
    {
        private static final HandlerEndPointAnalyzer    INSTANCE=new HandlerEndPointAnalyzer();

```
    private HandlerEndPointAnalyzer() {
        super(XTRACOperationType.COMMAND_HANDLER);
    }

    public static final HandlerEndPointAnalyzer getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
        protected EndPointAnalysis makeEndPoint(Frame handlerFrame, int depth) {
            Operation operation = handlerFrame.getOperation();
    String resourceLabel = operation.getLabel();
    String exampleRequest = EndPointAnalysis.getHttpExampleRequest(handlerFrame);
    return new EndPointAnalysis(EndPointName.valueOf(resourceLabel),
                                resourceLabel,
                                exampleRequest,
                                getOperationScore(operation, depth),
                                operation);
}
```

being sure to add it as a descriptor:

```
public class HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor extends PluginRuntimeDescriptor {
    public static final String PLUGIN_NAME = "handler";
    private static final HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor INSTANCE=new HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor();
    private static final List<? extends EndPointAnalyzer>   epAnalyzers=
            ArrayUtil.asUnmodifiableList(HandlerEndPointAnalyzer.getInstance());

    private HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor() {
        super();
    }

    public static final HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends EndPointAnalyzer> getEndPointAnalyzers() {
        return epAnalyzers;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPluginName() {
        return PLUGIN_NAME;
    }
}
```

All noted in the spring xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:insight="http://www.springframework.org/schema/insight-idk"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/insight-idk http://www.springframework.org/schema/insight-idk/insight-idk-1.0.xsd">

  <insight:plugin name="handler" version="${project.version}" publisher="XTRAC Solutions LLC" />


  <insight:operation-group group="XTRAC Handlers" operation="command_handler_operation" />
  <insight:operation-group group="XTRAC Handlers" operation="event_handler_operation" />
  <insight:operation-group group="XTRAC Classic" operation="xtrac_workflow_operation" />

  <insight:operation-view operation="command_handler_operation"
                          template="com/xtrac/insight/command_handler_operation.ftl" />
  <insight:operation-view operation="event_handler_operation"
                          template="com/xtrac/insight/event_handler_operation.ftl" />
  <insight:operation-view operation="xtrac_workflow_operation"
                          template="com/xtrac/insight/xtrac_workflow_operation.ftl" />

    <bean id="handlerPluginEndPointAnalyzer"
          class="com.xtrac.insight.HandlerEndPointAnalyzer"
          factory-method="getInstance"
          lazy-init="true"
        />
    <bean id="handlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor"
             class="com.xtrac.insight.HandlerPluginRuntimeDescriptor"
             factory-method="getInstance"
             lazy-init="true"
           />

</beans>
```

along with some `ftl`s.

I also created a `MethodOperationCollectionAspect` to collect some of the web service calls that occur in these handers.  This sets it up for a nice display that tells me a lot about what is going on during the hander operation, and how much time it takes.  E.g.
[image: Example of Spring Handlers with web service calls intermixed]

This set up a framework for maintaining a monitor on the health of the application if I set up the base line Thresholds for the named handlers

[image: Thresholds]

This is very useful because I can then tell if the application is healthy.  Otherwise, the endpoints default to <200 ms for healthy.
[image: Health]